# If Ethereum 2.0 won't reduce gas fees on mainnet, what will?

Tags: gas, erc-721, gas-limit, gas-estimate, eth-2.0

For much of 2021, people who buy and sell ERC-721s believed that Ethereum 2.0 would reduce gas costs, while knowing that the London Hard Fork that was released in summer would only help reduce gas volatility, but not gas costs. So they anticipated Eth 2.0 to be released by end of year. But it's apparent it's not coming at all in 2021.

Now all of a sudden they say that **Ethereum 2.0 will not reduce gas whatsoever**, and that it simply allows scaling and bundling of transactions. How the myth was finally debunked now after so much conviction all year is surprising and not clear.

Gas has been steadily high above 100 gwei for weeks now. What upcoming upgrade to mainnet *will* reduce gas costs? or is it completely impossible without aid from ZK-rollups, sharding, etc. Sharding is now half-decades away, another a huge myth all year, while Layer-2s are not a mainnet solution and shouldn't be brought up in any answer. How can the busiest digital asset network go on like this at such a high transaction cost?

Answer (score -2):

Yours is a practical, fact-based question:

> what will... reduce gas fees on mainnet?

And here is a fact-based answer:

> A change of leadership at Ethereum, starting with Vitalik.

---

The decision to not implement any type of meaningful scaling at Ethereum is a direct result of leadership priorities. Ethereum is not a democracy, it is simply a project run, like basically every other open source project, by a specific team. And this team has shown consistently that your feature request is not a priority.

Noted at: https://twitter.com/fulldecent/status/1435624919816101906

Comment: Cardano, Solana and Stellar have little to no gas, but their adoption, and quality of digital goods, are mediocre and shoddy

Comment: Agreed. What these projects need is an intense focus on developer adoption and ease of use. I have personally reached to several alt chains to advise on recreate the magic Ethereum has, and am in active discussion. But these projects make decisions thoughtfully and so strategic changes/investments take time. I'm on it.

Comment: anyway, since everyone is still trading digital goods on Ehtereum, and will likely not be switching to any other chain en masse for the medium-term, let's re-read the question and discuss its gas shall we

Comment: I have answered the question already. There is no technical problem to reducing gas costs, nearly every other chain has done this. The problem is simple a matter of appetite to implement this~~and the people that release Ethereum have decided not to do it.

Comment: how would they implement it?